# google play store says no connection retry

Tags: google-play-store, connection-issues

When I open the Google Play Store it says, ***no connection retry*** even when I am connected to wifi and when I hit Sign In in the Youtube app it says, **An error occurred.**

Comment: Have you ever been able to get to Play Store (or other Google services) on this phone?

Comment: See also: [Why does Google play show a "no connection: retry" error?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20855)

Comment: See also: [Always seeing "No connection: Retry" in Android Market](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15947)

Comment: See also: [Google Play Store gives error "No Connection"](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/40763)

Comment: See also: [Internet Apps are not working but browser works just fine and i am able to access websites](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/37061)

Comment: Read thIs , it helped me . mIne was the date was wrong. http://wccftech.com/fix-no-connection-retry-error-message-on-google-play-store-app/

Answer (score 0):

You checked your internet connection of the modem/router? I also got that problem several times.. > modem/router/ap restart helped me in this cases because it was a connectivity issue with my provider and not an android/app problem.
Sometimes even a simple turn into flight mode and back resolves this issue (at least for me).

Comment: To decide whether it's your router or rather the Android device, it might help checking the colors of your connection icons in the notification bar. If they are white/gray, the Google servers cannot be reached (so it might be the router/AP). If they are green/blue, the Google servers are reachable, so it's more likely something "messed up" on your device (in which case the flight-mode-switch might help).

Comment: The browser works

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a firewall app, make sure you've allowed the Play Store (or whatever other apps) in the firewall rules...AND that you've saved/updated the rules.

Apps like Android Firewall won't actually make the changes until you've chosen to 'Apply rules'.

Answer (score -1):

Mine Solved..

Some times your network blocks ip's or google may black list your network ip's for some reason.. 
If setting date and time, clearing data and cache doesn't work. Install VPN HotSpot Shield via browser. Than turn this app on once it secures your connection you will be good to use play store.

Hope this helps.