# Play store not connecting on MIUI rom

Tags: google-play-store, miui

After updating MIUI from 3.8.23 to 3.10.25, I get the annoying error message "No connection" when opening Play Store (which is version 4.3.11). Wifi is on and all other apps work fine. Tried to delete play store cache/data but didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: What "recent update"? Have you updated your MIUI version? Has the Play Store app updated? Or have you updated something else? Whatever you've updated, please give the version number if you suspect that is related.

Comment: @DanHulme I updated MIUI itself from 3.8.23 to 3.10.25 using the built in update tool. Play store version is 4.3.11 now, unfortunately I can't say what it was before update. Since miui doesn't come with play store built in, I thinks it the same version.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of [edit]ing that information into your question. While you're waiting for an answer, you might like to look at [the similar questions linked from here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46999/12442) to see if the answer from one of those applies to your situation.