# Unable To Open Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi, connection-issues, internet, data-connection

I've encountering a problem. The problem is that i can't access my Google Play on a my Wi-fi. It is not on a particular tablet or phone. Its all the devices me an my family own. That includes 4 phones and 2 tablets. It only says "No Connection" even when the Wi-fi signals are at full strength. I don't know if this is coincidental but recently I've been receiving this notification that says "Sign into Wi-fi Network". Guys please advice immediately because how can i download awesome apps without the awesome store and i'm not planning to let 3rd party apps populate our devices.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20855/why-does-google-play-show-a-no-connection-retry-error and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46999/google-play-store-says-no-connection-retry?rq=1 and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15947/always-seeing-no-connection-retry-in-android-market  and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40763/google-play-store-gives-error-no-connection

Answer (score 1):

"Sign into Wi-fi Network" says it all: No network, no connection. You most likely changed the password/keyphrase at your router, and forgot to adjust your devices. They cannot log in to the network anymore, hence you get that notification. Fixing your WiFi configuration will solve the other problem along.

**Edit:** Thanks to Dan for pointing out my omission: The phrasing of the notification indeed points to a "captive network", which requires a sign-in via browser first. To automate such a login, you might wish to take a look at [WiFi Web Login](http://www.appbrain.com/app/co.uk.syslynx.wifiwebloginapp) and [comparable apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=196#group_429). Also see [Automate web login for Wi-Fi hotspots (captive portal) on Android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3974/185) at our sister-site.

Comment: It doesn't say "sign into Wi-fi network" if the Wi-Fi password is wrong. It only says that on a captive network.

Comment: @DanHulme That's true, and I'm aware of that (which is why I didn't suggest to update the password on the router). My phrasing might be a little unfortunate here; thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Well as going by your point that the problem is not limited to you but to your whole family then the problem lies with the configuration of your modem.

1. If the wifi is not configured properly then it may or may not show
   connected but you will not be able to download or browse any content
   let it be Google play  or the internet.
2. As you have not specified any h/w details of your modem then I can
   only provide a general solution which would be to configure your
   modem properly either by yourself or from the relevant technician of
   the modem.
3. Also do please check whether the Wi-Fi is displaying a Red cross with an error
   of irrelevant settings on your Desktop or Laptop when connecting over the Wi-Fi or the connection is normal through the LAN Cable.
4. If its a yes for the LAN and Wi-Fi then you need to get your modem checked by the
   technician for both Wi-Fi as well as LAN Connection